# Malformed input-Unknown command: 'mon-put-metric-alarm'

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am configuring my aws ec2 ubuntu instance for autoscaling. I have set the launch config file and also auto scaling group. I was quite successful in setting up the auto scaling policy too. I have a return POLICY-ARN which has to be used to set the cloud watch policy.

When I run the command thats as-put-metric-alarm I am getting this

"Malformed input-Unknown command: 'mon-put-metric-alarm'"

I tried to solve it I am able to understand whats wrong actually.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. The problem was the PATH variables were not set properly.